# Highlight only the selected item

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a drop-down list where, when I hover over a specific element, I should highlight only the selected one, unfortunately the whole list is highlighted in my mind, I know the problem is that in one li there is also a new list to make a drop down menu, Unfortunately, I can not deal with it. It's actual result [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/reverse26/cqt2yp5L/1/)

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="parent">
                <a class="parent_click">Driving</a>
                <ul class="sub_list">
                    <li class="test">
                        <a class="sub_click">Type of Car</a>
                        <ul class="sub_sub_list">
                            <li>List 1</li>
                            <li>List 2</li>
                            <li>List 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="test">
                        <a class="sub_click">Tracks</a>
                        <ul class="sub_sub_list">
                            <li>List 1</li>
                            <li>List 2</li>
                            <li>List 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="teset">Type of driving</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.sub_list, .sub_sub_list {display:none;}

li:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
```

My JS

```
$(".sub_list").slideUp();
$(".parent_click").click(function() {
    $(".parent_click").not(this).next().slideUp()
    $(this).closest(".parent").find(".sub_list").slideToggle();

    return false;
});
$(".sub_click").click(function() {
    var elem = $(this).next()
    $(".sub_sub_list").not(elem).slideUp();
    $(this).closest(".test").find(".sub_sub_list").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using anchor for hover instead of li. It will be simplest and easiest solution. While you can play with code if you want complicated solution...
See below snippet.

```js
$(".sub_list").slideUp();
$(".parent_click").click(function() {
 $(".parent_click").not(this).next().slideUp()
 $(this).closest(".parent").find(".sub_list").slideToggle();

 return false;
});
$(".sub_click").click(function() {
 var elem = $(this).next()
 $(".sub_sub_list").not(elem).slideUp();
 $(this).closest(".test").find(".sub_sub_list").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.sub_list, .sub_sub_list {display:none;}
a:hover{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta
   name="viewport"
   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link
   rel="stylesheet"
   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
   crossorigin="anonymous">
 <title>Hello, world!</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li class="parent">
    <a class="parent_click">Driving</a>
    <ul class="sub_list">
     <li class="test">
      <a class="sub_click">Type of Car</a>
      <ul class="sub_sub_list">
       <li><a>List 1</a></li>
       <li><a>List 2</a></li>
       <li><a>List 3</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="test">
      <a class="sub_click">Tracks</a>
      <ul class="sub_sub_list">
       <li><a>List 1</a></li>
       <li><a>List 2</a></li>
       <li><a>List 3</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="teset"><a>Type of driving</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfect :) Now I'm trying to make it open the subpage after clicking the item and remember what I have clicked on and then expand the menu. Just like here in the left menu at oddsportal.com I click on the main category, I choose a sub-category, I click, the sub-page loads and the menu is expanded with the sub-category I last clicked.